# How can I echo out this array?

Tags: php, arrays

I don't know how I would go about grabbing the data in the variable and put it into a foreach loop.

```
class Tree{
  private $info = array(
    array('name'=>'Jim','state'=>'NU','company'=>'NU','phone'=>array('cell'=>'5615111111','office'=>'5611111111'),'email'=>array('primary'=>'exs@example.com','ex@there.com')),
    array('name'=>'Joe Smith','city'=>'Phoenix','phone'=>'4805551111','email'=>'jsmith@some_email.com'),
    array('name'=>'John Doe','city'=>'Chandler','company'=>'Doe Co.','email'=>array('jdoe@gmail.com','personal'=>'email@email.com'),'phone'=>'6025550002')
  );
}
```

Comment: um er: `foreach ($info ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're inside of the class, you can access your private variable using `$this->variableName`.  For example, if you use it in the __construct method, you could echo all the names like this:

Supposing you had this file called `Class.Tree.php`:

```
class Tree{
  private $info = array(
    array('name'=>'Jim','state'=>'NU','company'=>'NU','phone'=>array('cell'=>'5615111111','office'=>'5611111111'),'email'=>array('primary'=>'exs@example.com','ex@there.com')),
    array('name'=>'Joe Smith','city'=>'Phoenix','phone'=>'4805551111','email'=>'jsmith@some_email.com'),
    array('name'=>'John Doe','city'=>'Chandler','company'=>'Doe Co.','email'=>array('jdoe@gmail.com','personal'=>'email@email.com'),'phone'=>'6025550002')
  );
  public function __construct() {
    // Leaving this in for references' sake
    /* foreach ($this->info as $elm) {
     *   echo $elm["name"] . "<br/>";
     * }
     **/
  }
  public function getInfo() {
    return $this->info;
  }
}
```

Now in your view (body), you could use something like this:

```
<?php 
  // Watch this line that you really have a file called Class.Tree.php in the same directory!
  require_once 'Class.Tree.php';
  $tree = new Tree();
  $info = $tree->getInfo();
?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>City</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach ($info as $elm) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo (isset($elm['name'])) ? $elm['name'] : ""; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo (isset($elm['state'])) ? $elm['state'] : ""; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo (isset($elm['city'])) ? $elm['city'] : ""; ?></td>
      <td>
        <?php if (isset($elm['phone'])) {
          if (is_array($elm['phone'])) {
            foreach ($elm['phone'] as $key => $phone) {
              echo $phone . " ($key)<br/>";
            } 
          } else { 
            echo $elm['phone'];
          }
        } ?>
      </td>

    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: ah ok now I get it. Thank you so much:)

Comment: Do you actually want to use a `<table>` element?

Comment: Sorry - I based my edits on your previous comment that you deleted, but let me know if the update makes sense to you.

Comment: WOW! thank you! you are a life saver. Im sorry to bother you again but I have 1 more question. I keep getting an error that says "Array to string conversion"? like on the phone array how can I access that? do I have to do another foreach inside that foreach?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I have added code to show you how.  Watch out: not all of your phones are arrays to begin with, so you have to add a check before looping.  A better method, if possible, would be to put the phone in an array whether there are 0, 1, or multiple.

Comment: Ah ok I see but why do the phones get echo'd out the same I have 3 same phone numbers for the 2 names underneath the first array name?

Comment: NVM i see i just have to access $elm['phone']. Thank you such much for your help Jonathan:)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using the variable in the same class you can do this.

```
$arrVal = array();
$arrVal  = $info;

foreach ($arrVal as $val)
{
   foreach($val as $sing)
   {
     //access the value of each array with index. Eg: $sing['name']

   }

}
```

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
public function show() {
    foreach ($this->info as $node) {
        foreach ($node as $key => $value) {
            echo "key = " . $key . ", value = " . $value . PHP_EOL; // $value may be Array
        }
    }
}
```